# How can I Find and Extract first consecutive numeric digit string from text in multiple cells in a list in excel 2013?

Tags: excel-2013

I need to find and extract first consecutive numeric digits in a cell containing text in excel 2013.Please help me to execute this task.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that will pick the first number from the cell. That means that if the cell contains `1.23abc` it will pick 1.23, and not just the digit 1.

```
=LEFT(A1,SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))))))
```

- If the cell is is non-numeric, it will return a blank
- Otherwise the largest number that can be created by the leftmost digits is returned. The return value is text. If you want a number that you can calculate with, enclose the formula in a `VALUE(...)` function.